# VBA- MS ACCESS- Add/Remove library references do not persist after re-opening access file

Tags: vba, ms-access, reference

VBA library references changes do not persist when changed by code?
Trying to make code compatible for a number of machines that are a mix of windows 7/10, some that have AutoCAD 2018, and some AutoCAD 2021.
my solution is as per below:
I have a "startup" form that will add all required references via the below subroutine on startup.

```
Sub CheckRef(RefName, GUID, Major, Minor)
Dim IsMyReferencePresent As Boolean
Set oRefs = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References
IsMyReferencePresent = False
For Each oRef In oRefs
        If oRef.GUID = GUID Then
            IsMyReferencePresent = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    If IsMyReferencePresent = False Then
    On Error Resume Next
        oRefs.AddFromGuid GUID, Major, Minor
    End If

End Sub
```

I also have a "running" form that is open in the background and on close of DB, it will remove all loaded references using the below code.

```
 Sub DelRef(GUID)
 Set oRefs = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References
 For Each oRef In oRefs
 If oRef.GUID = GUID Then
 oRefs.Remove oRef
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 End Sub
```

I also have a routine to output current library references.
as you can see below, just before close , i have successfully removed the references, but on open, they are back still loaded.

## Before Access Close

- Item - Name and Description
- Item 1    VBAVisual Basic For Applications
- Item 2    AccessMicrosoft Access 15.0 Object Library
- Item 3    VBIDEMicrosoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
- Item 4    ScriptingMicrosoft Scripting Runtime

## On Access Open

- Item 1        VBA           Visual Basic For Applications
- Item 2        Access        Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library
- Item 3        VBIDE         Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
- Item 4        Scripting     Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Item 5        stdole        OLE Automation
- Item 6        DAO           Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library
- Item 7        Office        Microsoft Vbe UI 7.1 Object Library
- Item 8        ADODB         Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
- Item 9        AutoCAD       AutoCAD 2021 Type Library

so why are these references persisting even though they are removed?

My first initial thought is that a further recompile is needed before closing access to save the changes.
however, doesn't VBA recompile on ref changes?
I have tried the below code to recompile but it produces a loading DLL failed error.

```
 Sub compileMe()
 Dim objVBECommandBar As Object
 Set objVBECommandBar = Application.VBE.CommandBars
 Dim compileMe As CommandBarButton
 Set compileMe = objVBECommandBar.FindControl(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=578)
 If compileMe.Enabled = True Then compileMe.Execute
 If compileMe.Enabled = True Then Debug.Print "Error Compiling"
 End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You must save the file after removing them. Your code (probably) saved the file after adding them. Not necessarily in the same piece of code...

Comment: Could try late binding code and then don't have to select library references. https://www.excelcise.org/add-or-remove-object-library-reference-via-vba/

Comment: But why bother removing the references, when they successfully have been added and also are needed for any following launch? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, seems like Late binding is the answer. however now , some systems don't even have Autocad and access will throw an error on startup. i think now this calls for separating front and back end, and develop a slightly different front end with AutoCAD code portions take out?